# Select from one datasource update another

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-web-developer

I am using Visual Web Developer to create a form updating my database.  Currently, I fill a gridview based on two drop down lists querying against a view in my SQL 2008 database.  This works fine, but I cannot update a view directly, so what I need to do is update the main table that supports the view.  So here is the question(s).  Can I have a select statement that says

```
SELECT * FROM [vw_GridviewSource] WHERE (([Annotation Date] = @Annotation_Date) AND ([Name] = @Name))
```

And have an update to another table?

Also can I somehow only allow the user to update certain fields and not others?  I have an instance where the "Annotation Number" is actually generated by my client and should not be changed, but I do want them to be able to update notes, business unit etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulty in understanding your question[s].

> Also can I somehow only allow the user to update certain fields and
>   not others?

Short answer yes. Following example grant UPDATE on Name column and deny UPDATE on OrganizationNode column for User007.

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Department TO User007;
GRANT UPDATE (Name) ON dbo.Department TO User007;
DENY UPDATE (OrganizationNode) ON dbo.Department TO User007;
GO
```

Now you can connect using this user and execute following statements:

```
PRINT 'SELECT >';
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Department;

PRINT 'UPDATE #1 >';
UPDATE  dbo.Department
SET     Name = NULL;

PRINT 'UPDATE #2 >';
UPDATE  dbo.Department
SET     OrganizationNode = NULL;
PRINT 'End of Test';
GO
```

Results:

```
SELECT >
DepartmentID Name                                               OrganizationNode
------------ -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE #1 >
UPDATE #2 >
Msg 230, Level 14, State 1, Line 13
The UPDATE permission was denied on the column 'OrganizationNode' of the object 'Department", database 'Test', schema 'dbo'.
```

Comment: Bogdan, I think I understand what you are showing with GRANT UPDATE.  My issue originates with the SELECT statement that is associated with my GRIDVIEW.  It uses a datasource that is a view from SQL.  I want this to remain a view but I also want to allow the users to update the table behind the view with limited access to fields.  So I may have select * from vw_Master as the query for the GRIDVIEW.  I would like to say UPDATE notes from tb_Master for each row selected.  Does that help?

Comment: Then the main question is if this view is updatable ? See [Remarks > Updatable Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).

Comment: I tried doing an update to the view in SQL and it worked.  I guess that you learn something new everyday.  My only question is whether I can have an edit and update when I don't have a primary key.  If you can help me with that, I believe I have the query written for the update.

Comment: (1) What is the reason for this restriction: " when I don't have a primary key" ? (2) Did you tried to execute an update on an [updatable view] which references a table without a PK ?

Comment: The datasource for a gridview needs to have a primary key in order to activate the advanced functions (insert,update,delete) according to the literature.  I am finding that sometimes that only refers to the standard functionality.  I can add edit, update, cancel programmatically without a PK.